# Rename Columns with names from another data frame

Tags: r

I'm learning R programming as such have hit a few problems - and with your help have been able to fix them.

But I now have a need to rename columns of a data frame. I have a translation data frame with 2 columns that contains the column names and what the new columns should be called.

Here is my code: my question is how do I select the two columns from the **trans** dataframe and use them here as *trans$old* and *trans$new* variables?

I have 7 columns I'm renaming, and this might be even longer hence the translation table.

```
replace_header <- function()
{      
  names(industries)[names(industries)==trans$old] <- trans$new
  replaced <- industries
  return (replaced)
}  

replaced_industries <- replace_header()
```

Comment: Use `colnames` function.

Comment: You probably want the `match` function.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks, how do I go able using match? please forgive my ignorance :(

Comment: You need to include the output of `dput(industries)` and `dput(trans)` in your question.

Comment: Assuming your rows in your `trans` df are in the same order as the columns in your main df why can't you just do `names(DF) <- trans$new` ?

Comment: @Warner The columns in my main df are about 34 in total - and I'm only renaming just 7. So they don't numbers don't match. I might be complicating things though...:)

Comment: Something like `names(new_df)[which_seven] <- names(old_df)[which_seven]` should be fine.

Comment: You can index the column numbers of your DF which you wanna change and index the row numbers of the new names you want. Suppose you want to rename columns 7 - 14. and you want to use rows 21 - 28 in your transition data frame: `names(industry)[7:14] <- trans$new[21:28]`

Comment: @Warner, substituting by index seems error-prone. Safer to match by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example using the built-in `mtcars` data frame. We'll use the `match` function to find the indices of the columns names we want to replace and then replace them with new names.

```
# Copy of built-in data frame
mt = mtcars

head(mt,3)
```

> ```
>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
> ```

```
# Data frame with column name substitutions
dat = data.frame(old=c("mpg","am"), new=c("new.name1","new.name2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat
```

> ```
>   old       new
> 1 mpg new.name1
> 2  am new.name2
> ```

Use `match` to find the indices of the "old" names in the `mt` data frame:

```
match(dat[,"old"], names(mt))
```

> ```
> [1] 1 9
> ```

Substitute "old" names with "new" names:

```
names(mt)[match(dat[,"old"], names(mt))] = dat[,"new"]

head(mt,3)
```

> ```
>                   new.name1 cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs new.name2 gear carb
> Mazda RX4              21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0         1    4    4
> Mazda RX4 Wag          21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0         1    4    4
> Datsun 710             22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1         1    4    1
> ```

Comment: Why a downvote? This is essentially what I do when reading data with silly col names.

Comment: Just curious, why the downvote? If you think I've done something incorrect or sub-optimal, please let me know, so I can improve my code.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for the code above. I'm struggling to see how to make it fit into my little function above. Could someone help point out how it could be improved? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need a new function to do it. Just do `names(industries)[match(trans[ ,"old"], names(industries)] = trans[ ,"new"]`.

Comment: Also, instead of `match`, you could do `which(names(industries) %in% trans$old)`.

Comment: I think `match` is better than `%in%`. If some `trans$old` does not appear in the names, it'll be harmless with `match` (like `x[NA_integer_] = y`, doing nothing), but screw things up if done the other way. Also, with `%in%`, row order of `trans` has to match col order of the table.

Comment: @eipi10 - thanks for the code above. The match function did it for me as you suggested. I can't tell you how thrilled it feels to see it working. I know... I know...i'm quite excited. I'm loving R programming.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `setnames` from "data.table" for this. Using @eipi10's example:

```
mt = mtcars
dat = data.frame(old=c("mpg","am"), new=c("new.name1","new.name2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
setnames(mt, dat$old, dat$new)
names(mt)
#  [1] "new.name1" "cyl"       "disp"      "hp"        "drat"      "wt"       
#  [7] "qsec"      "vs"        "new.name2" "gear"      "carb"
```

If there's a concern as indicated by @jmbadia that the `data.frame` with the old and new names, you can add `skip_absent=TRUE` to `setnames`.

Answer (score 0):

improving a bit the eipi10's answer, if we want to use a "rename dataframe" with old names not always present on the mt dataframe (e.g. because mt is provided by differnt sources so we don't always know its colnames) we can consider the following code

```r
mt = mtcars

head(mt,3)
```

> ```
>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1   4     4
> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1   4     4
> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1   4     1
> ```

```r
# dataframe with possible names to replace
dat = data.frame(old=c("strangeName","am"), new=c("new.name1","new.name2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# find which old names are present in mt
namesMatched <- dat[dat$old %in% names(mt)
#renaming
names(mt)[match(namesMatched,"old"], names(mt))] = dat[namesMatched,"new"]

head(mt,3)
```

> ```
>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs new.name2 gear carb
> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0     1       4    4
> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0     1       4    4
> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1     1       4    1
> ```