# change variable names from a list of names in R

Tags: r, rename

I have a dataset called "df" and it has 5 variables called year, v1,v2,v3,v4. I have also another dataset (i.e. df_name) including two columns of old_name and new_names. The old_names contains the current name of the variables in "df" and the new_names contains the variable names that I want to assign to variable names of the "df".

So, I am trying to find a solution by which, the code looks for the variable names in "df" that are in the old_names variable of df_name and replace it with the corresponding new_names value. In fact, I am expecting something like "df_expected"

In my real dataset, I have more than 1000 variables, so I have to use the old_name and new_names in df_names that is, I cannot refer to each variable name individually.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried to use the solution here: [Rename Columns with names from another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921405/rename-columns-with-names-from-another-data-frame), however, it did not work. Applying the code to my case like so

```
names(df)[match(df_names[,"old_names"], names(df))] = df_names[,"new_names"]
```

returns the error:

```
#> Error in names(df)[match(df_names[, "old_names"], names(df))] = df_names[, : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

```
df <- data.frame(year = 2019:2020, v1=1:3, v2=4:6, v3=7:9, v4=10:12)

df_names <- data.frame(old_names = c("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5"),new_names = c("A","B","C","D","E"))

df_expected <- data.frame(year = 2019:2020, A=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9, D=10:12)
```

Comment: When you say "did not work", what does that mean exactly? What code did you try and what result did you get?

Comment: @MrFlick The issue is that `df_names` does not contain a new name for the `year` column of `df`.

Comment: By not working I mean the match finds NA matching cases. I used match names(df)[df_names[,"old_names"],names(df)] = df_names[,"new_names"]

Comment: Just `subset` the values of `df_names` to only keep those that match before doing the replace: `df_names <- subset(df_names, old_names %in% names(df))`. It looks the the answer from jmbadia already did this from the other question. Be sure to check out all the answers on duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can set name in data.table without mentioning old names

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setnames(df, c('year','A','B','C','D'))
```

Comment: I think `setnames(df, as.character(df_names$old_names), as.character(df_names$new_names), skip_absent=TRUE)[]` is probably more in line with what they might be looking for.